# Update frame after each iteration

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, port, port-scanning

I am currently coding a port-scanner in Qt(C++) for Mac. The process of checking if a certain port is open or not works completely fine. **But** if the port range which the user wants to check is too big, every port will be checked but the output happens only after this process.
The program actually should check for example port 1 and output the result. After that it should check the next and output and so on...

```
void MainWindow::checkPort(int portmin, int portmax, string ip) {
int dif = portmax - portmin;
if (dif <= 0)
    return;

unsigned int open = 0;
unsigned int closed = 0;
int checked = 0;

sockaddr_in addr;
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip.c_str());

for (int i = portmin; i <= portmax; i++) {
    int s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    addr.sin_port = htons(i);

    int con = ::connect(s, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&addr), sizeof(sockaddr));

    if (con == 0){
        ui->textEdit->setTextColor(Qt::green);
        ui->textEdit->append("Port " + QString::number(i) + " open.");
        open++;
    }

    if (con == -1) {
        ui->textEdit->setTextColor(Qt::red);
        ui->textEdit->append("Port " + QString::number(i) + " closed.");
        closed++;
    }

    ::close(con);
    ::close(s);
    checked++;
}
```

Have you got any advise how I could have an **output after each iteration**?

Comment: You might want to put a call to [`QApplication::processEvents()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) into your loop, to give the UI a chance to process messages and show updates.

Comment: @KarstenKoop Thank you very much! That solved my problem.

Comment: Your code blocks the gui. Stop blocking the gui and everything will be fine. You **are** having output after each iteration, but you never *return* to the event loop, so the UI has no chance to refresh itself. **Do not** use `processEvents`. Treat any use of this method as a bug. It's an asynchronous world, don't write code that pretends otherwise and you'll save yourself lots of trouble.

Comment: @KarstenKoop This reenters the event loop and simply hides the fact that the port scanner shouldn't have been written that way to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to run the whole scanning job concurrently using the thread pool. The inter-thread communication is done safely via the signal-slot mechanism:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/async-portscan-39469180
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtConcurrent>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

class Scanner : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    bool running = false, stop = false;
    int open = 0, closed = 0, total = 0;
    void scan() {
        running = true;
        sockaddr_in addr;
        addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
        for (int i = 1; i < 65536 && !stop; ++i) {
            auto s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
            addr.sin_port = htons(i);
            auto con = ::connect(s, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&addr), sizeof(sockaddr));
            emit hasResult(i, con == 0);
            con == 0 ? ++open : ++closed;
            ++total;
            ::close(s);
        }
        emit done();
        running = false;
    }
public:
    ~Scanner() {
        stop = true;
        while (running);
    }
    Q_SIGNAL void hasResult(int port, bool open);
    Q_SIGNAL void done();
    Q_SLOT void start() {
        QtConcurrent::run(this, &Scanner::scan);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    using Q = QObject;
    QApplication app{argc, argv};
    QWidget ui;
    QVBoxLayout layout{&ui};
    QTextBrowser log;
    QProgressBar bar;
    QPushButton scan{"Scan localhost"};
    layout.addWidget(&log);
    layout.addWidget(&bar);
    layout.addWidget(&scan);
    bar.setRange(1, 65535);
    ui.show();

    Scanner scanner;
    Q::connect(&scan, &QPushButton::clicked, &scanner, [&]{
        scan.setEnabled(false);
        scanner.start();
    });
    Q::connect(&scanner, &Scanner::hasResult, &log, [&](int port, bool isOpen){
        bar.setValue(port);
        if (!isOpen) return;
        auto color = isOpen ? QStringLiteral("green") : QStringLiteral("red");
        auto state = isOpen ? QStringLiteral("open") : QStringLiteral("closed");
        log.append(QStringLiteral("<font color=\"%1\">Port %2 is %3.</font><br/>").
                   arg(color).arg(port).arg(state));
    });
    Q::connect(&scanner, &Scanner::done, &scan, [&]{
        bar.reset();
        scan.setEnabled(true);
    });
    return app.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

```
//...
bool tooManyPorts = dif > 10000; // Set flag to true if port range is too big (for example more than 10 000 ports
// 
QString msgs = "";
for (int i = portmin; i <= portmax; i++) {
    int s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    addr.sin_port = htons(i);

    if (con == 0){
        if (tooManyPorts) {
            QString("<font color='green'>Port " + QString::number(i) + " open.</font><br/>");
        }
        else {
            ui->textEdit->setTextColor(Qt::green);
            ui->textEdit->append("Port " + QString::number(i) + " open.");
        }
        open++;
    }

    if (con == -1) {
        if (tooManyPorts) {
            msgs += QString("<font color='red'>Port " + QString::number(i) + " closed.</font><br/>");
        }
        else {
            ui->textEdit->setTextColor(Qt::red);
            ui->textEdit->append("Port " + QString::number(i) + " closed.");
        }
        closed++;
    }
    // ...
}
if(tooManyPorts) {
    ui->textEdit->append(msgs); // Add all iteration messages to text edit
}
```

Note the usage of HTML for the formatting part.

This adds all the output to your field AFTER the loop. To get it to work for each iteration just set `msgs = ...` and not `msgs += ...` in the loop and then move the `if(tooManyPorts) ...` at the end of your `for` but not outside. Frankly I have difficulty understanding whether you don't want the first version (AFTER the loop) since right now you **are** adding your output to your text field in each iteration step.

Comment: Oh, I want that the output is added to the text field after every iteration step, but with my code it doesn't happen in reality even if it actually should. But I am going to give your solution a try. **UPDATE:** Doesn't work as well. The output is added as a whole and not step by step.

Comment: Hmm, can you provide more information on you text edit object like its properties. I have an application which adds multiple strings based on received events every couple of milliseconds and I have no problem. Please refine your question.

Comment: I solved the problem with @Karsten Koop 's suggestion. The problem was that `append` has been called too often in a short period of time so the GUI was not able to refresh and update with every iteration step.

Comment: Oh, my...You do the processing of your ports inside the main thread... :-/ You should really consider adding a separate thread for this (see [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details)). Also you can add the ability for outputting small subsets of your information for example for every 10 ports collect the info (as I have written in my post using `QString`) and then add it. Generally you need to avoid doing too much stuff in the main thread.